# Kotlin - Functionally Traverse Collection getting current/next value

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, is there a functional way to traverse through a `List<T>` getting a `Pair<T,T>` that reflect the current/next element.

E.g. - the imperative approach would be something like

```
for (index in 0 until list.size-1) {
        val current = list[index]
        val next = list[index + 1]
        //do calculations on current/next.
    }
```

Something like `list.forEachPaired { it: Pair<String,String?> ->//do something }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html) (see link for the parameters). If you want to work with `Pair`s in particular, you can use the overload with `transform`:

```
list.windowed(2) { Pair(it[0], it[1]) }.forEach { ... }
```

but I'd just write

```
list.windowed(2).forEach { ... }
```

where the parameter of `forEach`'s lambda is a `List<T>` of length 2.

Answer (score 4):

Although `windowed()` is powerful, there's a slightly simpler alternative in this case: [`zipWithNext()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html).  For example:

```
list.zipWithNext().forEach{ (first, second) ->
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not only simpler, but also more efficient than `windowed` when called as `zipWithNext { first, second -> ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alexey Romanov that the intermediate `Pair`s are not necessary really. You can destructure your windowed lists in a `forEach` lambda:

```
list.windowed(2).forEach { (first, second) ->

}
```

Comment: Love this - only ever looking 2 values so saves me working with a list